# convert csv file to json object with Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, csv

I am doing a project with Laravel 7. I have to read a csv file and through a controller passing the data in json format to a view.
Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

These are my controller methods:

```
public function index($source)
{
    $source = strtolower($source);

    switch ($source) {
        case "csv":
            $file_csv = base_path('transactions.csv');
            $transactions = $this->csvToJson($file_csv);
            dd(gettype($transactions));
            return view('transactions', ['source' => $source, 'transactions' => $transactions]);
            break;
        case "db":
            $transactions = Transaction::all();
dd(gettype($transactions));
            return view('transactions', ['source' => $source, 'transactions' => $transactions]);
            break;
        default:
            abort(400, 'Bad sintax error.');
    }
}

function csvToJson($filename = '', $delimiter = ',')
{
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
        return false;
    }
    $header = null;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== false)
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false)
        {
            if (!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

As you can see, under the two cases I put a `dd` with a `gettype` function inside. In the first case I receive uncorrectly the response array, in the second one I receive correctly the response object.

The converted csv file should have this format:

```
[{"id":1,"code":"T_218_ljydmgebx","amount":"8617.19","user_id":375,"created_at":"2020-01-19T16:08:59.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-01-19T16:08:59.000000Z"},
{"id":2,"code":"T_335_wmhrbjxld","amount":"6502.72","user_id":1847,"created_at":"2020-01-19T16:08:59.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-01-19T16:08:59.000000Z"}]
```

Do you know how to convert the array `transactions` into a json object in the first case?

Comment: not really sure what you are asking here and there is no "json object" ... are you asking how to `json_encode` something into a JSON string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is any build-in solution on Laravel, but it can be done by PHP.

I didn't test my code. So it might not work, or contain some typos, but I'm sure it will give you some directions.

```
$cols = ["id","code","amount","user_id","created_at","updated_at"];
$csv = file('folder/name.csv');
$output = [];

foreach ($csv as $line_index => $line) {
    if ($line_index > 0) { // I assume the the first line contains the column names.
        $newLine = [];
        $values = explode(',', $line);
        foreach ($values as $col_index => $value) {
            $newLine[$cols[$col_index]] = $value;
        }
        $output[] = $newLine;
    }
}

$json_output = json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this :

```
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', explode(PHP_EOL, $csv));
$json json_encode($array);
```

If you want to return json object

```
return $json;
```

If you want to create a .json file

```
// Pure PHP 

$file = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);

// Laravel using Storage 
Storage::disk('local')->put('public/result.json', $json);
```

I hope this helps somone.

Answer (score 0):

I have an email marketing application where I made bulk importers. So here is their CSV TO JSON code.

```
function convert_csv_to_json($csv_data){
      // CSV to JSON process 1
        $context = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'follow_location' => false,
                'max_redirects' => 1000000
                )
        );
        
        $context = stream_context_create($context);

        if (($handle = fopen($csv_data, "r", false, $context)) !== FALSE) {
        $csvs = [];
        while(! feof($handle)) {
        $csvs[] = fgetcsv($handle);
        }
        $datas = [];
        $column_names = [];
        foreach ($csvs[0] as $single_csv) {
            $column_names[] = $single_csv;
        }
        foreach ($csvs as $key => $csv) {
            if ($key === 0) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($column_names as $column_key => $column_name) {
                $datas[$key-1][$column_name] = $csv[$column_key];
            }
        }
        
        return $json = json_encode($datas);
    
    }

    // OR

    // CSV to JSON process 1

    $cols = ['id', 
        'owner_id', 
        'name', 
        'email', 
        'country_code', 
        'phone', 
        'favourites', 
        'blocked', 
        'trashed', 
        'is_subscribed', 
        'deleted_at', 
        'created_at', 
        'updated_at.'];

    $csv = file($csv_data);
    $output = [];

    foreach ($csv as $line_index => $line) {
        if ($line_index > 0) { // I assume the the first line contains the column names.
            $newLine = [];
            $values = explode(',', $line);
            foreach ($values as $col_index => $value) {
                $newLine[$cols[$col_index]] = $value;
            }
            $output[] = $newLine;
        }
    }

    return $json_output = json_encode($output); 

}
```